# Unicode string to bytes back to unicode string is not invariant

Tags: ruby, unicode

In Ruby 2.3.3, I enter the following code

```
require 'scanf'

def hex2str(x)
  if x !~ /\A([0-9a-fA-F]{2})+\z/ then return nil; end
  x.scan(/.{2}/).map{|k| k.scanf("%x")[0].chr}.join
end

def str2hex(s); s.bytes.map {|k| "%02x" % k}.join; end

s="ü"
t=hex2str(str2hex(s))

p s
p t
s.bytes
t.bytes
```

I get the following output:

```
"ü"
"\xC3\xBC"
[195, 188]
[195, 188]
```

Why is `s ≠ hex2str(str2hex(s))` even though `s.bytes = hex2str(str2hex(s)).bytes` ?

It seems that somewhere, automatic normalization of some sort is taking place. Is there a way to avoid this? Can you provide versions of `hex2str` and `str2hex` which do not disturb the bytes in any way and which satisfy `s = hex2str(str2hex(s))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, an instance of a `String` object consists of a sequence of bytes along with the *encoding* that Ruby believes those bytes to be in. In order for two strings to be equal they basically need to have *both* the same bytes *and* the same encoding (there is some complication dealing with “ascii-compatible” strings, but essentially this is the case).

You can change this encoding tag without changing any of the bytes using [`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-force_encoding).

As an example, the byte 0xC0 when interpreted in the encoding ISO-8859-1 is `À`, but in ISO-8859-2 it is `Ŕ`. Clearly these are not the same, even though they contain the same bytes:

```
# Use the optional argument to chr to specify the encoding to
# use when creating the string.
i1 = 0xC0.chr("ISO-8859-1")
i2 = 0xC0.chr("ISO-8859-2")

puts i1.bytes # => 192
puts i2.bytes # => 192

puts i1.encoding # => ISO-8859-1
puts i2.encoding # => ISO-8859-2

puts i1 == i2 # => false
```

In your case, since you don’t specify what encoding to use when calling `chr`, Ruby defaults to using ASCII-8BIT, which basically means a binary encoding. The resulting string therefore has a different encoding, and Ruby considers it as different from the original.

Since you know the encoding the string should be, you can get your example to work by adding a call to `force_encoding` after the `join` in `hex2str` to tell Ruby the encoding (here I’m assuming the original string encoding is UTF-8):

```
x.scan(/.{2}/).map{|k| k.scanf("%x")[0].chr}.join.force_encoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: There’s a pretty good explanation at http://graysoftinc.com/character-encodings/ruby-19s-string.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I have in the meantime came up with the following version which also seems to work. `def hex2str(x);
  if x !~ /\A([0-9a-fA-F]{2})+\z/ then return nil; end;
  x.scan(/.{2}/).map{|k| k.scanf("%x")[0]}.pack('C*').force_encoding('utf-8');
end` Your explanation now helps me understand why.